# Given `=match(true,index(x1:x$1000="",0),0)`, what is the index function doing?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've seen this form of `match` and `index` in multiple places as an answer to the question "How do I total all values in a column until the first blank?", and it does work. But I want to understand how the `INDEX` function works here; the definition of the function says its first argument should be a range, and in this case the first argument is a range, and equals operator, and the empty string.

I can see that `MATCH()` is returning the index of the first element of the range that matches the conditional, but where does it say that `INDEX()` takes a conditional as its first argument? What are the rules for that?

Examples are good, but they often don't tell you how to do slightly different things later.

Comment: The index is returning an array of true/false based on the Boolean.  The 0 on the index tells the index to return the whole array.

Comment: Ok, great. I gather you mean "based on the expression". Is there a reference to the function somewhere that says that it can take an expression and return an entire array? and what values besides 0 are possible for the 2nd argument? (Well, now that I look at the Office support page for the Index function, I see what you're talking about. If you put this in an answer, I'll accept it.)

Comment: Looking at it a third and fourth time, I think the thing I was missing was not so much a feature of the `INDEX` function as it is a feature of something I'll call 'range expressions' since I don't know the term Microsoft/Excel gives it. It's the usage of `x1:x$1000=""` to produce an array of booleans. If you (or anyone) happen to know what specific terminology they use for that in Excel documentation, that would be useful so I can look it up.

Comment: I found this reference.. that mentioned index() is capable of 4 types of output. relavant to this question the "use zero for the row_num argument" is also mentioned in this ( https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-functions/excel-index-function ) ref.